# Overcome META NAME="robots" for an rest get client

Tags: java

The below is the rest response for a server.

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?">
</script>
<script>
(function() { 
var z="";var b="7472797B766172207868723B76617220743D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D652829";for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z = z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

Actual Response got from the Rest client when used POSTMAN :

```
   "query": {
        "offset": 0,
        "count": 20,
        "total": 379
    }
```

How to overcome or get the actual response from the REST client using HTTPGet client?

Comment: The below is the code which i have used using jersey client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this resolved with by adding a SSL connections related code in it. Due to which it recognized and authenticated this request and responded back with the valid response.

This is a safety net feature implemented by the firewall in most of the public API's due to which it try's to identifies any such request and mark those as a ROBOT when there header information is incorrect.